# Good structures for removing vertices from black-white trees

Tags: python-2.7, tree, binary-tree, game-theory, tree-structure

I want to program a tree (in a mathematical view) in Python 2.7 where each vertex is white or black. Then I want to be able to remove leafs to create a new tree. Note that the root can be a leaf if it only has one connection and therefore it can be removed.

Is there some way to find an ID for the tree so I can store values for different trees in a list? I also want to make a loop for different small trees, for examples all trees with 8 or fewer vertices with all possible black-white colorings.

One idea is to start with binary trees since it could be to complex otherwise.

Is there any good structures for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree?

Comment: Yes, but does there exist a smart library/module/etc in Python 2.7 that I can use instead of creating my own?

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic here on SO. You may be able to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap instead, by the way.